# MS Flow - "Get-manager" does not work in my approval Flow

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to setup a Flow that works with Sharepoint online vacation calendar.

I was wondering if any of you guys can hint me in the right direction as MS Flow dev. forums are inconsistently active and sometimes I have to wait quite a while to get an answer.

So my deal is this - I have a flow setup, and by the logic in it it should work fine, but there is a step called "Get manager" and it fails to get the sid from Azure AD manager field (this field is not empty in my Azure AD).

My flow looks like this:
[see this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFhc7.png)

I tried this command in Powershell with the latest Azure module installed:

Get-AzureRmADUser -UserPrincipalName

and it did not return the email of any user I tried with. So I'm suspect there maybe something missing the Azure AD settings, but I'm not sure entirely.

Comment: What does your get manager task do?

Comment: It retrieves manager's email of the user who created an item in the Sharepoint Online vacation calendar. Then the Flow progresses, otherwise it stops if no email is supplied.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the manager information of azure ad user using powershell , you could invoke the Graph API directly , since PowerShell essentially wraps the API's and just presents them to you in a simplified interface. Please refer to below article for how to call Azure Active Directory Graph Api from Powershell :

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/paulomarques/2016/03/21/working-with-azure-active-directory-graph-api-from-powershell/

And use the [Get a user's manager API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetUsersManager) :

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/XXXXXX/$links/manager?api-version=1.6
```

And here is the result :

```
PS C:\Users\v-nany>  $tenant = "testbasic1.onmicrosoft.com"
PS C:\Users\v-nany>  $token = GetAuthToken -TenantName $tenant
PS C:\Users\v-nany> $authHeader = @{
>>    'Content-Type'='application\json'
>>    'Authorization'=$token.CreateAuthorizationHeader()
>> }
PS C:\Users\v-nany> $uri = "https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/testnanyu@testbasic1.onmicrosoft.com/$links/m
anager?api-version=1.6"
PS C:\Users\v-nany> $ManagerInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri –Headers $authHeader –Method Get –Verbose
VERBOSE: GET
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/testnanyu@testbasic1.onmicrosoft.com//manager?api-version=1.6 with
0-byte payload
VERBOSE: received 1240-byte response of content type
application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8
PS C:\Users\v-nany> $ManagerInfo


odata.metadata                 : https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/$metadata#directoryObjects/@Element
odata.type                     : Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User
objectType                     : User
objectId                       : 9e6efc2c-69b7-4da2-8ef5-9c8624e76a52
deletionTimestamp              :
accountEnabled                 : True
signInNames                    : {}
assignedLicenses               : {}
assignedPlans                  : {}
city                           :
companyName                    :
country                        :
creationType                   :
department                     :
dirSyncEnabled                 :
displayName                    : NANYU
facsimileTelephoneNumber       :
givenName                      :
immutableId                    :
isCompromised                  :
jobTitle                       :
lastDirSyncTime                :
mail                           :
mailNickname                   : testnanyu1222
mobile                         :
onPremisesSecurityIdentifier   :
otherMails                     : {}
passwordPolicies               :
passwordProfile                : @{password=; forceChangePasswordNextLogin=True; enforceChangePasswordPolicy=False}
physicalDeliveryOfficeName     :
postalCode                     :
preferredLanguage              :
provisionedPlans               : {}
provisioningErrors             : {}
proxyAddresses                 : {}
refreshTokensValidFromDateTime : 2017-04-03T07:03:00Z
showInAddressList              :
sipProxyAddress                :
state                          :
streetAddress                  :
surname                        :
telephoneNumber                :
usageLocation                  :
userPrincipalName              : testnanyu1222@testbasic1.onmicrosoft.com
userType                       : Member
```

If i misunderstand your requriement , please feel free to let me know .

Comment: For now I'm just getting a blank line after I run this, although the SID is there in Azure AD.. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you correctly set clientId &&tenant  with above code ? using a tool like fiddler to check whether any error occurs.